# Insert dd/mm/yyyy date format into database table

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert a dd/mm/yyyy date format into my database table. The data type for date column in database is date and my SQL insert statement is:

```
INSERT INTO sm_product(productName, productDescription, productPrice, productQuantity, productStatus)
VALUES ('" + name + "', '" + desc + "', " + price + ", " + quantity + ", 'Available', '" + date + "'";
```

However, netbeans shows me an error when I added the date variable into the SQL statement.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

And it stores the date as:

> Wed Jun 19 17:42:26 SGT 2013

And I got my dd/mm/yyyy date format in user interface:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = new Date();
dateFormat.format(date);
```

This format is not I wanted. So I wonder how should I amend my SQL statement to fix the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you really want another date format. You can use a varchar column in your base, and give a formatted string in parameters.

Comment: But I thought using date data type is better? Because I need to get the month from date later on. Can I do this with varchar?

Comment: To get the month, you can split the string and get the MM. But don't forget, I don't know if it is the better solution, but it can be a solution.

Comment: You should use parameters and keep datetime data in variables with a `datetime` type throughout. These types don't *have* a format. You should apply formatting as late as possible in output, and you should parse dates from strings as early as possible for input. By the time you're talking to the database, it should only ever be `datetime` variables.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am sorry but can you please give me some example? Because I am kind of confused

Comment: @Carol - well, you've not tagged your question with what technologies you're working with. If I assume MySQL (that's at least mentioned in the error message) and Java (because it has a `SimpleDateFormat` class), then a google search for `java MySql Prepared Statement` would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server , you can use

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),date,105),'-','/')
```

Comment: Ya I am using it. So I modify my insert statement to: "INSERT INTO sm_product(productName,productDescription,productPrice,productQuantity,productStatus) VALUES ('" + name + "', '" + desc + "', " + price + ", " + quantity + ", 'Available', '" + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),date,105),'-','/') + "'";?

Comment: But there is an error at the varchar there. I code this using netbeans

Comment: cannot find symbol. symbol: method varchar(int)

Comment: Above answer won't work ... you are using MySQL ... Above works for MSSQL Server

Comment: But is there any other ways to fix this?

Comment: The question wasn't tagged correctly but the error message clearly states **MySQL** (no matter what the OP claims).

Answer (score 0):

If you insert following format sting into query, record will be updated

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date date = new Date();
String formatDate = dateFormat.format(date);
```